# Configure Azure (Kubernetes) Network Security Group to support multiple Source IP addresses for same destination port

Tags: azure, kubernetes, internal-load-balancer, network-security-groups

We are using Kubernetes with Azure as cloud provider. The relevant setup to my question is that we have one loadbalancer and one network security group which is attached to all worker VMs. So basically every time I create a service, it creates a record in LoadBalaner frontend IP configuration, and adds a rule in network security group with specified destination port and Source IP addresses (which restricts from which source IP it can access the VM in which port.)

The problem with this set up is that, if I have a service that uses port 5000 which is open to public IP, and another service that also uses port 5000 but is open to only specific IP, both services are effectively open to public IP, because NSG rules are additive. Note that 5000 port number here does not represent the actual VM node port (although that's what Azure thinks) because it's taken care by kube-proxy in each machine and it will send the traffic to correct VM with corresponding node port. And this is why it makes sense to have two services using same port with different ingress rule set up.

Is there any way I can mitigate this problem? I can't think of any architecture setup I can deal with having different ingress rule for multiple services with same destination port.

Thank you

Comment: Azure NSG associate with NIC or subnet, it seems NSG can't achieve your goal. Maybe we can limit the source IP addresses in docker.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT I think we can achieve my goal by specifying destination ip address on each of nsg rule. If I have a rule with port 5000 that allows packet from Internet, but only to destination ip of its front-end ip, it will not override the other rule with port 5000 that allows packet from certain ip address. Right?

Comment: For now, Azure NSG does not support block network traffic by destination IP address. When we expose a service to Internet, Azure will create a new Public IP address for it. Azure NSG can't associate to public IP, so we can't use NSG to limit the network traffic. Can we set the limit in docker image?

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT hmm I just confirmed I can block network traffic by destination IP address. For example if a frontend IP is 'a', and in nsg it has port:10000 , destination IP 'a', and open to Internet, one still cannot access IP 'b' with port 10000, because it doesn't have any corresponding rule in nsg.